# Which picture correctly shows a crossover wire for networking?

Tags: networking, cable, crossover

Why are there crossover cable diagrams/dipictions that show two different wiring formats? I always thought the first pic below was the correct way to format a crossover cable? I've never seen the way that the second picture depicts. **PS, this question is not a duplicate because I am asking for a clarification on which picture more accurately represents the format of a crossover wire, it does not give any clarification or explanation on the second method...**

**Crossover format that I believe to be correct:**

[image: Crossover format that I believe to be correct]

**Crossover format that I believe to be wrong:**

[image: Crossover format that I believe to be wrong]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either would have worked back in the days of 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX, because those standards only used two pairs: 1&2 and 3&6.

But 1000BASE-T and 10GBASE-T use all four pairs, so you have to cross them all over like in the second image if you want gigabit and 10G to work.

So the one you thought was wrong was a little more right than the one you thought was right.

Comment: Would you still recommend using the wiring format depicted in the second picture even if I don't plan on using gigabit and 10G?

Comment: If your 1000BASE-T (and 10GBASE-T)  equipment is new enough to have Auto-MDI/MDIX, then the half-right crossover cable could be okay (but not even necessary).  *"Not planing on using Gigabit"* is shortsighted.

Comment: But it wouldn’t hurt to use the second picture, right?